# lexical scope in R

Tags: r, lexical-scope

I recently learned that R has both lexical and dynamical scoping available, but that it uses lexical scope by default. The next case really confused me:

```
> x <- 1
> f <- function(y) { x + y }
> f(5)  # we expect 6    
[1] 6
> x <- 10
> f(5)  # shouldn't we again expect 6?
[1] 15
```

Shouldn't `f` be evaluated using the environment where (and at the time!) it was  *defined*  and not where it was  *called* ? How is this lexical scope? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f <- function(y) { x + y }
```

was defined in the global environment and so for the parts not defined in the function itself (i.e.`x`), R looks to the global environment for them.

```
a=1
b=2
f<-function(x)
{
  a*x + b
}
g<-function(x)
{
  a=2
  b=1
  f(x)
}
# compare f(2) and g(2)
```

This example above is from [here](http://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/lexical-scope-and-function-closures-in-r/) and gives a good discussion. Main point being, `f()` within `g()` ignores the definitions of `a` and `b` in `g()`.

---

From the [wiki on "Scope"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29)

> In object-oriented programming, dynamic dispatch selects an object method at runtime, though whether the actual name binding is done at compile time or run time depends on the language.

Comment: Yes I get that part, but shouldn't it also use the environment *at the time* it was defined? I edited my question to make that part more clear.

Comment: I not sure I see why it should, as it rechecks the environment at each call. Remember `R` was developed with an interactive programming approach in mind.

Comment: So, using the environment *at the time* you where defined is not part of the definition of lexical scope? Or is this simply not lexical scope what R uses?

Comment: No I think you are correct that lexical scope can mean using the time at definition. I guess my point is that r just uses the location and so is not dynamic in that respect

Comment: This discussion was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This behavior in R is what is known as lexical scope with dynamic lookup.